# How to allow HTML tags in WPF text block with binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I defined a TextBlock in xaml with binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MyClass, Path=MyStringProperty}"/>
```

When I set `MyStringProperty` to , for example , `<b>Hello, World!</b>` it shows it as plain text. Is there a way to tell the control to make the `Hello, World!` string bold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with a `TextBlock` like that.

You need to bind the `FontWeight` property of the text block to a variable that holds the bold/not bold value.

If the value is a boolean you need to write a converter to map the boolean value to the font weight property.

If you want to change the boldness (or any other property) of the text at runtime based on what the user types in then you need to be looking at using a `RichTextBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Inlines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines.aspx) property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MyClass, Path=MyStringProperty}">
    <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding BoldText}" />
</TextBlock>
```